# C#/.net/multithreading: Calling memberfunctions on generic collections

Tags: c#, generics, collections

Is this always correct?

Let's take a list and call a meberfunction eg "Find" on it. While Find is in progress another thread updates the reference "list" to a new list. Does this have any effect on the result of "Find" or any other memberfunction of the collection?

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

        string s = list.Find(e => {
            list = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" }; // <- this line shall happen in another thread
            return e == "c";
        });
```

I don't know the internals, but is it garantied that the reference (in this case "list") is only read once, before Find starts executing?

Comment: A method call on an **object** doesn't care whether you re-assign a different **object** to the **variable** that originally pointed to the first **object**.

Comment: Just a side-note: If you *want* multiple threads to operate on the same collection you probably should use one of the tread-save implementations. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, theoretically if you run `LINQ` query on a collection it will use Lists `GetEnumerator` function that will return enumerator object that *knows* how to enumerate collection *without* using the variable that holds the reference to it.

That's why in this example:

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            list.Find(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"El:{e}  Hashcode:{list.GetHashCode()}");
                Thread.Sleep(750);
                return e == "z";
            }).ToList();
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            list = new List<string>();
        });
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Output is:

```
El:a  Hashcode:63835064
El:b  Hashcode:63835064
El:c  Hashcode:11454272
El:d  Hashcode:11454272
```

Comment: But Find() is not Where().FirstOrDefault(). Is there anything officially documented on how these things work?

Comment: @be_mi Updated my answer. With `Find` it's working in the same way for the same reasons